# ReadPreference PRIMARY Error mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replication

I am using nodejs with mongo db.I am configuring the replset server like below.WHenever i tried to do read operation i am getting error like **No replica set primary available for query with ReadPreference PRIMARY and no writer connection available**.

`var options = {
    strict: false,
    journal: true
};
var replSet = mongodb.ReplSetServers(servers,{rs_name:process.env.RSNAME || 'rs0'});
var  mongoClient = new Db(process.env.DBNAME||'test',replSet,options);`

     how can i able to set the read preference as prmiary ?

Comment: You don't need to. It is the default read preference.

Comment: Most likely, you simply don't have a primary in you replica set. Remember that you always need an uneven number of voting members. Please add the output of `rs.status()` to your question by editing it.